# MongoDB- dealing with huge collections

Tags: mongodb, bigdata

I have one huge MongoDB collection which contains hundreds millions of documents (e.g. 300m, 400m and still growing). What is the best solution to ensure that queries and aggregations will run fast? I have some ideas, which one is the proper one?

1. Splitting the data into few smaller collections.
2. Storing initially agreggated data in separate collections so for the most common queries/ agrregations the result can be returned quickly.
3. Adding proper indexes- does it make sense to add indexes to such big collection?
4. Leave one collection and distribute this data accross multiple machines (sharding)? Does MongoDB cope with such collections which are distributed over few or more machines?

Are there any better solutions which I missed?

Answer (score 2):

1. Splitting the data into few smaller collections.

   Makes only sense when your queries and aggregations are limited to such smaller collections. If your query has to join several collections then you don't gain so much. Your queries would be more complex.
2. Storing initially aggregated data in separate collections so for the most common queries/ aggregations the result can be returned quickly.

   Could make sense, however you create redundant data which may become inconsistent to your actual data. Apart from that you need more disc space.
3. Adding proper indexes- does it make sense to add indexes to such big collection?

   Definitely a good idea. It would be **very** surprising if such big collection does not have any indexes.
4. Leave one collection and distribute this data across multiple machines (sharding)?

   Definitely also a good idea. To certain extent this is similar to (1) but MongoDB deals with splitting and joining, so you don't need to care about it.